# jqgrid filter toolbar not working

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to implement the filter toolbar in my jqgrid.
But whenever I enter anything in any one of the filter toolbar search box, the "Loading" pop-up comes and stays there and nothing happens then. Below is the snapshot:

[image: The Error]

Below is  my jqgrid code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#workQueueGrid').jqGrid('GridDestroy');
    $("#workQueueGrid").jqGrid({
        url:contextRoot+'workQueueGrid',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: ['ID','Received','Last Name','First Name','Aa','Bbbb', 'Source', 'Ddddd', 'Ccccc', 'Eeeeee', 'Fffffff', 'Ggggggg', 'Hhhhhhh'],
        colModel: [
                   { name: 'Id', index: 'referralId', width: 30, sortable:true },
                   { name: 'receivedDate', index: 'receivedDate', width: 50, formatter: function(cellValue){return $.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', new Date(cellValue));}, sortable:true },                   
                   { name: 'lastName', index: 'lastName', width: 55, sortable:true },
                   { name: 'firstName', index: 'firstName', width: 55, sortable:true },
                   { name: 'data1', index: 'data1', width: 30, sortable:true },
                   { name: 'data2', index: 'data2', width: 30, sortable:true },
                   { name: 'data3', index: 'data3', width: 40, sortable:true, cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;"'; } },
                   { name: 'data4', index: 'data4', width: 30, sortable:true, cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;"'; } },
                   { name: 'data5', index: 'data5', width: 40, sortable:true, cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;"'; } },
                   { name: 'data6', index: 'data6', width: 50, formatter: function(cellValue){return $.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', new Date(cellValue));}, sortable:true },
                   { name: 'data7', index: 'data7', width: 50, formatter: function(cellValue){return $.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', new Date(cellValue));}, sortable:true },
                   { name: 'data8', index: 'data8', width: 50, formatter: function(cellValue){return $.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', new Date(cellValue));}, sortable:true },
                   { name: 'data9', index: 'data9', width: 80, sortable:true, cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;"'; } }
        ],loadError: function(xhr,st,err) {
            alert(err);
        },onSelectRow : function(rowid, status, e) {
            var selRow = $(this).getGridParam("selrow");
            var selReferralId = $(this).getCell(selRow, 'referralId');
            window.location = (contextRoot+"referralDetails?refId=" + selReferralId );            
        },
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
        },
        pager: '#workQueuePager',
        sortname: 'receivedDate',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        gridview: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce: true,
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        height: 'auto',
        rowNum: 12,
        ignoreCase: true,
        altRows:true
    }); 

    $("#workQueueGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#workQueuePager',
       {
        edit:false,
        add:false,
        del:false,
        search:false,
        refresh:false
    });

    $("#workQueueGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar',
        { 
         stringResult: true, 
         searchOnEnter: false,
         defaultSearch: "bw"
    });
});
```

Sample Data:

```
    {"rows":[{"receivedDate":1357016400000,"referralId":23450,"lastName":"Smith","firstName":"John","goCode":"A99","zoneCode":"NE","sourceName":"Source Name","status":"Pending","actionAS":"AS Action","vpReportDate":1357016400000,"approvedDate":1357016400000,"lastModifiedDate":1357016400000,"workflow":"Recommendation(s) required"},{"receivedDate":1357102800000,"referralId":23451,"lastName":"Smith","firstName":"John","goCode":"A99","zoneCode":"NE","sourceName":"Source Name","status":"Pending","actionAS":"AS Action","vpReportDate":1357102800000,"approvedDate":1357102800000,"lastModifiedDate":1357102800000,"workflow":"Recommendation(s) required"},{"receivedDate":1357189200000,"referralId":23452,"lastName":"Smith","firstName":"John","goCode":"A99","zoneCode":"NE","sourceName":"Source Name","status":"Pending","actionAS":"AS Action","vpReportDate":1357189200000,"approvedDate":1357189200000,"lastModifiedDate":1357189200000,"workflow":"Recommendation(s) required"},
```

Not sure, what am I missing here?!?

**Update 1:**

```
Below is the error I'm getting:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAccessor' of undefined
```

**Update 2**

Below is the JSP:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="<c:url value="/js/workQueue.js"/>"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        th.ui-th-column div {
          white-space:normal !important;
          height:auto !important;
          padding:2px;
     }  
    </style>    
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span style="font-size: 18px"><b>${status == 'pending' ? 'Pending': 'Approved'}</b></span><br/><br/>
                There are ${workQueueCount} referrals ${status}. Click a row to see details.<a href="<c:url value="/excelExport"/>" id="excelExport" style="float: right;">Export To Excel</a>               
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="5px">
            <td>                            
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="dartWorkQueueGrid"></table>                              
                <div id="dartWorkQueuePager"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Handler method:

```
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/workQueueGrid") 
    @ResponseBody 
    public JqgridResponse loadWorkQueue() {
        this.referrals = dartService.getReferralCases(status);       
        JqgridResponse response = new JqgridResponse();
        response.setRows(referrals);

        return response;
    }
```

This is JqgridResponse.java:

```
    package com.nyl.corp.disciplinaryactions.web;

import java.util.List;

public class JqgridResponse {

    public JqgridResponse(List<?> rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public JqgridResponse() {
    }

    private List<?> rows;

    private int page;

    private int total;

    private int records;

    public void setRows(List<?> rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public List<?> getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(int page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public int getRecords() {
        return records;
    }

    public void setRecords(int records) {
        this.records = records;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 3**
Snapshot of the grids inside the tabs:

[image]
[image]

**Update 4**
Tabs JSP Code:

```
    <script>    
    $(function() {
        $( "#workQueuesTab" ).tabs();
    });    
</script>  
</head>
<body>
      <div style="width:95%" id="workQueuesTab">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="<c:url value="/workQueue/pending"/>">Pending</a></li>
              <li><a href="<c:url value="/workQueue/approved"/>">Approved</a></li>
              <li><a href="<c:url value="/workQueue/additionalSteps"/>">Additional Steps</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>            
</body>
```

Comment: From my past experiences, the issue you are describing happens when a server error occurs.  Are you receiving a valid response from your server?

Comment: @Kyle I'm implementing client side filtering. The data is getting loaded from the server fine, that's why it is getting displayed in the grid. Also I'm not getting any server error.

Comment: @Kyle I've updated the question with the sample JSON data that is returned from the server.

Comment: Thank you for the sample data.  I copied/pasted your code and sample data, but cannot reproduce your problem.  What version of jqGrid/jQuery are you using?  I am using jqGrid 4.4.4 with jQuery 1.8.2

Comment: @Kyle I'm using jqGrid 4.4.1 with jQuery 1.10.0 Also I checked I'm getting the following error:
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAccessor' of undefined
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
v.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
execute
select
la
G
b.before.click.bind.dblclick.A
v.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:2
o.handle.u jquery.min.js:2
v.event.trigger jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:2
v.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
v.fn.v.each jquery.min.js:2
v.fn.extend.trigger jquery.min.js:2
e
(anonymous function)

Comment: I am guessing you meant you are using `jQuery UI 1.10.0`, but what version of `jQuery` are you using?  If you are indeed using jQuery UI 1.10.0, I would recommend upgrading to jqGrid 4.4.4 which is the version they fixed many of the bugs relating to the redesign in 1.10.0.  http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Comment: @Kyle I'm sorry! I'm using jquery 1.8.3 and jquery UI 1.9.2

Comment: After using jQuery 1.8.3, UI 1.9.2, and grid 4.4.1, I'm still unable to reproduce the problem.  I am, however using a local data type.  My suggestion is this, after looking at your code: 1) Make sure you `grid.locale-*` is loaded before the `jqGrid` source and 2) I see you are using a `json` datatype for the initial server response.  Inside your `colmodel`, make sure to add a `jsonmap` field which specifies which field inside the server response maps to which field in the colmodel.

Comment: @Kyle Do I really need to add the jsonmap in colmodel, because the data is successfully displayed in the jqgrid with the current code.

Comment: You don't have to.  It was just a suggestion.  I copied/pasted your code and uploaded it to a web server so I could make ajax calls (using save jquery, ui, and grid as you).  I still do not get the error message you are receiving.  Perhaps there is another issue on your page?  On a side note, you should change `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false,}` to `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false}` (no comma)

Comment: @Kyle When you say that you are not receiving the error message, so is the filtertoolbar working fine for you?

Comment: Correct.  I am able to pull data from the server, and filter it using the toolbar.

Comment: @Kyle Ahhh..This is really killing me..I'm also able to pull the data from the server, but the filter tool bar is not working! :(

Comment: @Kyle I've updated the question with the JSP and the Server side code. Does it make any sense to you?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know much about JSP.  Is this jQuery code the only Javascript on your page?  If it isn't, try commenting out all the other Javascript to see if your code works by itself.

Comment: @Kyle Yes that is the only JS on my page.

Comment: I'm sorry that I was unable to help you with your issue.  The only difference between your sample code and mine is that you are using JSP and I am using PHP (although, that shouldn't matter).  Same jQuery, UI, Grid, HTML, and I am even using the contextRoot variable.  If you manage to find out what the problem is or anything else that may help, I would love to hear it.  It's bugging me that this is happening haha.

Comment: @Kyle Oh sure..will let you know if I find the resolution! Its killing me too! Thanks though for all your help.

Comment: @Kyle Hey I'm back! I forgot to mention you initially that my grids are inside jQuery tabs. I've updated my question with the snapshot of the same. So, now what is happening is: When I remove the tabs the filtering function works perfectly fine. So is there an issue with jQgrid filter toolbar when grid is inside tab

Comment: Can you please post the initialization code for your tabs?  I use jqGrid inside of tabs and dialogs a lot and have never had any issues with the filter toolbar.

Comment: @Kyle I've updated the question with the Tabs JSP code.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is where my lack of JSP knowledge may lead me to not be able to help you.  I see your tabs are loading AJAX content and the AJAX content has its own initialization inside of the head?  Try moving that initialization into the `activate` method of tabs and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In the file jquery.jqGrid.js,

it calls jQuery by  jQuery.    Looks like your settings doesnt recognize it this way. try to change jQuery. to $. everywhere in the file.

It did work for me.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAccessor' of undefined (it doesnt understand jQuery. but it does $.)